# How to delete intermediate object files after build in scons

Tags: scons

I want to delete the intermediate object files after creation final output binary.

For example, let's say I've two source files (a.c and b.c) and SConsruct file. In SConstruct,

```
Program('out_bin', source=['a.c', 'b.c'])
```

scons command creates three binary files ('out_bin', 'a.o', and 'b.o')

Now I only want to keep the final binary file ('out_bin') and remove 'a.o' and 'b.o' .

What I need to do in SConstruct to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCons doesn't support this directly, but you can use python's atexit to run any python code after SCons completes.

Take a look at:
http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2834

Comment: It works. I followed your link and changed the SConstruct files

import atexit

@atexit.register
def remove_object_files():
    import os
    import glob
    print 'Removing object files ..'
    for tmp in glob.glob("*.o"):
        os.remove(tmp)
        print 'Delete ' + str(tmp)
    print 'All object files removed'

Program('out', source=['a.c', 'b.c'])